# Rails-Jquery-Autocomplete avoid duplicates

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete

I have a rails app with an "Order" model and a "Customer" model. The customers frequently have the same company so I added the [Rails-Jquery-Autocomplete](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete) field to the form.

I configured the form normally except in the controller I set

```
autocomplete :customer, :company
```

instead of

```
autocomplete :customer, :name
```

In my form I have

```
= f.autocomplete_field :company, :autocomplete_customer_company
```

The field works as intended however, it will show repeated instances of the same company if more than 1 customer exists with that company.

I found this on the documentation of the gem

> Running custom code on selection
>
> A javascript event named railsAutocomplete.select is fired on the
> input field when a value is selected from the autocomplete drop down.
> If you need to do something more complex than update fields with data,
> you can hook into this event, like so:
>
> $('#my_autocomplete_field').bind('railsAutocomplete.select',
> function(event, data){   /* Do something here */
> alert(data.item.id); });

Though I'm not familiar enough with either Rails or Javascript to properly apply it. (If this is even helpful)

Comment: I don't think js event hook is what you're looking for. That fires when a value is selected, after the list of values (with the duplicates you're trying to eliminate) are already being display. The [scopes option](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete#scopes) looks more promising. Try adding a scope to your model that filters out duplicates, then include that scope as an option in the `autocomplete` call in your controller.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I'll look into this option.  I'm still new to Rails so I'll get back to this when i figure it out.

Comment: @klenwell Hey, I hadn't had a chance to do this last week.

I'm trying to write the scope but it doesn't seem to have an effect

 scope :companies, -> {order("company DESC").select("DISTINCT company")}

Comment: A couple sanity checks: 1) Is your new scope returning a unique list of companies? 2) Are you referencing the scope in autocomplete as [documented here](https://github.com/bigtunacan/rails-jquery-autocomplete#scopes)?

Comment: I just checked the scope in irb, it does seem to return the values I want

Comment: The scope is in the RFQ controller as such

  autocomplete  :customer, :company, full:true, :scopes => [:companies]

I think that's correct but maybe I'm just not seeing something.

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this?